# Family of hash functions which are epsilon-almost universal

Tags: hash, universal-hash

Let $R, S,$ and $T$ be finite, non-empty sets. Suppose that for each $r \in R,$ we have a function $h_r: S \rightarrow T.$ In other words $\{h_r\}_{r \in R}$ is a family of keyed hash functions from $S$ to $T$.

We say that a family of hash functions $\{h_r\}_{r \in R}$ is pairwise independent, if for all $s, s' \in S, s \neq s'$ and for all $t, t' \in T$

$$
Pr[r\stackrel{$}{\leftarrow}R: h_r(s)=t\wedge h_r(s')=t']=\frac{1}{|T|^2}.
$$

We say that the family of hash functions $\{h_r\}_{r \in R}$ is $\epsilon-$almost universal, if for all $s, s' \in S, s \neq s',$

$$
Pr[r\stackrel{$}{\leftarrow}R: h_r(s)=h_r(s')] \leq \epsilon
$$

(a) Show that if a function family is pairwise independent then it is $\frac{1}{|T|}$-almost universal.

(b) Let $p$ be an odd prime. For $a,b \in \mathbb{Z_p}$ define $h_{a,b}: \mathbb{Z_p} \to \mathbb{Z_p}$ by the rule

$$
h_{a,b}(x)= (x+a)^2 +b \hspace{0.2cm}(\mbox{ mod } p)
$$

Prove that the family $\{h_{a,b}\}$ is $\frac{1}{p}$-almost universal.

Let me write down what I have tried.

(a) $\forall s, s' \in S, S \neq S'$ and for all $t, t' \in T$

$Pr[r \stackrel{$}{\leftarrow}R: h_r(s)=t \oplus h_r(s')=t']=\frac{1}{|T|^2}$

$Pr[r \stackrel{$}{\leftarrow}R: h_r(s)=t^{'} , h_r(s')=t' \oplus t=t'']=\frac{1}{|T|^2}$

Now consider $t^{'}=t^{''}$, then we have $|T|$ choices for $t^{'}$.

Then,

$Pr[r \stackrel{$}{\leftarrow}R: h_r(s)= h_r(s')]=\frac{1}{|T|}$

Hence $h$ is $\frac{1}{|T|}$-almost universal.

(b) Let $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{Z_p},$ where $x_1 \neq x_2$

$h_{(a,b)}(x_1)= h_{(a,b)}(x_2) (\mbox{ mod } $p$)$

$\implies (x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2+2a)=0 (\mbox{ mod } $p$)$

$\implies x_1+x_2+2a=0 (\mbox{ mod } $p$)$

Since there will be $p$ choices for $x_1$ and $x_2$ will be calculated according to $x_1$. So there are $p$ possibilities.

Hence, Pr[$h_{(a,b)}(x_1)= h_{(a,b)}(x_2)]=$\frac{1}{p}$.

The family $\{h_{a,b}\}$ is $\frac{1}{p}$-almost universal.

Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: Hint: suppose you have $x, y$ with $x \ne y$ and $h_{a,b}(x) = h_{a,b}(y)$ - what can you deduce about $a$?  If $a, b$ are randomly chosen, what is the probability that, for that specific $x, y$, we have $h_{a, b}(x) = h_{a, b}(y)$?

Comment: I have written down my approach. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: "Since there will be $p$ choices for $x_1$ and $x_2$ will be calculated according to $x_1$."; that's not how I would put it.  Instead, for any specific $x_1, x_2$ pair, there is a unique value $a$ that satisfies this; hence if $(a, b)$ is chosen randomly, there is a probability $1/p$ that the $a$ chosen will be that specific value.  The notation is perhaps a tad confusing; normally, we let $x$ denote the unknown; here, $x_1, x_2$ are constants

Comment: Can anyone help me with part b?